# From user-created data to database in Excel (maybe with XML?)

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning everyone,

Here is my problem ; I am currently trying to help the accounting department in my company with the creation of the budget. The basic idea is that there are several Excel workbooks which contain different data (such as HR costs, G&A costs, etc.) and which have to be modified manually by the user. My job is to find a way to consolidate all these numbers in a general budget file.

**The way it's done now:** For now, they have an Excel file with a lot of links to those HR_costs.xlsx files, which look like "VLOOKUP(SUMIF([S:\Accounting\Somefile]Some_sheet!$A4:G9) etc.", ie unreadable. Plus you have to update links every time you open the file and for some of them, because they've moved or renamed them, the links are broken and it simply doesn't work at all.

**What I'm trying to implement:** I think the best way to do it would be to have an excel database-like file on which the user could perform filtering, sorting, and create pivot tables. So what I'm trying to figure out is a simple way to go from those user-created files to a database.

**What I've tried so far:** After searching for answers on google for my problem (I believe what I'm trying to do is called 'unpivot'), I found an answer involving XML maps. So I've tried to write some XML map for the HR costs file, that looks like this : [HR costs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeDL6.png) (I've put a VLOOKUP in column B so you simply select the year you want in B1 and the data appears in column B, so that the only data to consider for XML export is in columns A and B)

And here is the XML map I wrote :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="Cost_Report">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Exp_Type" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Year" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Values" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Employee_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="NET" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs ="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>

  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Which works for one expense type (here Salary). However, there are several expense types on that workbook, located each below the other, so I wanted to iterate the process for each of them, while keeping the same 'Year' for all of them.

Here is the map I wrote for that:

```
<xs:element name="Year" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element name="Salary">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Exp_Type" type="xs:string"/>

          <xs:element name="Values" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Employee_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="NET" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs ="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>

      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Salary_Charges">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Exp_Type" type="xs:string"/>

          <xs:element name="Values" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Employee_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="NET" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs ="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>

      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:element>   


</xs:schema>
```

(Here for only two expense types). But when I load it to excel it gives me:

```
An XML error has occured. Please correct the problem and try again. 
[Details] Description : /schema/element[1][@name='Year']/element[1][@name='Salary']
Element 'xs:element' is not allowed in this context
```

I must confess I still don't understand it.

**Please help me** The reason why I've made a long post to explain my problem is that I'm not sure XML maps is necessarily the answer, if you have any other suggestion it would be greatly appreciated. I hope I've stated my problem clearly, but please don't hesitate to ask me for precisions.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is it possible to create a template that each department can complete and then use VBA to consolidate into a master file? Or use VBA to take the template data, create tables, and upload to an Access database?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess VBA would work but I was kind of saving that as a last option... Concerning your second suggestion, is it easy to go from tables to Access database? Do you think it would be doable if the user completes tables manually ?

Comment: Yes, if your data is structured properly it is very simple to import an Excel spreadsheet into an Access database. It's difficult to say what your tables/template would look like without knowing the data/purpose.

Comment: Based on your question, you might have a table for each department. HR_Tbl, Finance_Tbl, etc. Perhaps the fields would start with Cost_Type_# and then Cost_Type_Desc, and Cost. In Access you could then run Update Queries to combine each Table into one master table or simply query all the tables based on need. Example, SELECT Master_Tbl.[Cost_Type_#] FROM Master_Tbl WHERE Master_Tbl.[Cost_Type_#] = '5'

Comment: I'm currently working on that, it seems to be doing what I wanted. Thanks again!